# Difference between top-level variable and static variables

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, deno

I started TypeScript with deno and tried to use Static in one of my POC but it doesnt seem to do what I think it does.

Could  someone explain to us why in the following code getConn() seems to instantiate a new connection when called from another class

```js
import { Store, Id } from "./Store.ts";
import { Redis , connect } from "https://denopkg.com/keroxp/deno-redis/mod.ts";
    
export class RedisStore<T extends Id> extends Store<T>{
  static conn?:Redis;
  name:string;

  constructor(name:string){
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }

  async getConn():Promise<Redis>{
    if(RedisStore.conn == null || RedisStore.conn.isClosed){
      RedisStore.conn = await connect({
        hostname: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 6379
      });
    }   
    return RedisStore.conn;
  }
}
```

while if I declare before my class

```js
const redisconn = await connect({
  hostname: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 6379
});
```

and then change

```js
async getConn():Promise<Redis>{ return redisconn }
```

Obviously static doesn't work the way I expect it to do (like in c#) but I don't understand how.

RedisStore is instantiated as a singleton (I tried different things)

```js
export class User extends DataObject<UserData> {
      
  static store:Store<UserData>; 

  constructor(){
    super();
    if(!User.store){
      User.store = new RedisStore<UserData>(User.name)
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry if this question is trivial, and If you have any relevant doc Ill be glad if you share it!

Comment: Please expand upon "Obviously static doesn't work the way I expect it to do (like in c#) but I don't understand how."  It is not obvious to me as a reader of the question what you expect/don't expect.  Consider explicitly organizing your question as "I expected A, but received B", or "In C# static means ..., and I expect TypeScript static to mean ..."

Comment: I expect that ultimately await connect({
  hostname: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 6379
});  can only be called once in my program but it is called on every getConn instead

Comment: [`Static properties`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties) are nothing more than properties on the class itself, rather than the instance.  Not much to explain there.  I'm guessing your issue is not related to `static`.  I could not verify anything about the test `conn.isClosed` in the docs for the Redis library.  Are you sure your guard condition is correct?

Comment: I think you qre right the problem might be about the redis Ive tried guarding with a static boolean and I get the expected 1 call only but all the other calls have the conn undefined for some reason :(